# Как расширить размер максимальной команды в os python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, cmd, powershell

Для запуска окон при запуске приложения использую данную команду: `os.system('команда')`, но моя команда видимо слишком велика для cmd, она просто не вставляется до конца. Поэтому команда не выполняется. С библиотекой subprocess то же самое. Можно ли как-то обойти это ограничение?

Команда представляет из себя команду `powershell -enc` и длинющий код закодированный в base64. Немного поковырявшись я обнаружил что такого ограничения нет в powershell, но как запустить его в os/subprocess я не знаю(просто команда powershell не помогает есстественно).

Вот сам код упаковывания:

```
with open("data/cmd_to_exe.py", 'w+', encoding='utf-8') as prepairing:
    prepairing.write('import os\n')
    for code in codes:
        prepairing.write(f'os.system("{code[0:-1]}")\n')
```

P.S. этот код позже преобразовывается в exe, поэтому я всё записываю в файл, но по факту, всё работает как и по запросу компилятора.

Comment: Можете создать временный файл (`.bat` или `.ps1`), запустить его, а потом удалить файл.

Comment: @ΝNL993, Спасибо за помощь! Я попробую задействовать этот функционал:)

Comment: можно просто поток команд направлять на cmd.exe/powershell.exe через popen, тогда временный bat-файл не понадобится

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Длинная команда (для `os.system()`? <- нет, тогда: base64-декодированная команда PowerShell прямо там)? кодируем powershell-вызов в `base64`->временный `batchfile` -> его вызывает `python`.

Откомментируйте, если не помогло, т.к., мне кажется, работает, т.к. делал упаковщики-трансляторы синтаксиса бинарников внутри `Batchfile` через кодирование `certutil`. А у Вас тем более, `Python` да `PowerShell`.

Но Вы не тот фрагмент кода скинули. Надо код вызова, либо, если вызов работает, проверить целостность файла. Вот так и появляется профессия тестировщика.

//лирика (о своём): а я всё гадал, почему же так форсится команда тестирования в `npm`, но теперь все сомнения отпали, спасибо.

Comment: Да, для cx_Freeze я добавил файл codes.ps1 в билд и потом написал os.system("powershell -file codes.ps1"), но я остановился на сборке приложения напримую из кода powershell (ps2exe).